# jQuery autocomplete pre-filtered results - show all

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an ajax function which searches a database of users. All usernames get put into an array like

```
var usernames = ["Mike Scott", "Mike Whosname", "Mike Johns", "Mike Nicolas"];
```

So simply, I want the autocomplete to just display whatever is in this array. Either that or turn the search off completely so it doesn't filter my results for a second time.

The reason for this is, my SQL code also searches userid's so if I type for example "mscott", my servlet returns "Mike Scott" which gets put into the `usernames` array.

I want them to be able to select "Mike Scott" if they input "mscott".

The autocomplete is trying to search my array for "mscott" which is not displaying any results so I want it to just simply display everything in my array.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Current code:

```
$('#userInput').autocomplete({source: usernames, search: "", minLength: 0}).keyup(function(){

var url = "/AJAX/SearchUsers.do?searchQ=mscott";
        $.ajax(url, {
          type: "GET",
          datatype: "json",
          success: function(data) {
            for (var i =0; i < data.length; i++) {
              usernames.push(data[i].username);
          }
        }
      });
    $(this).autocomplete("option", {source: usernames, search: "", minLength: 0});

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem and it was a small issue I simply overlooked but still worth answering my own question just case someone else hasn't considered this before.

My problem was because my results are pre filtered, I was resetting the `usernames` array on key up to display a brand new set of results.

However, the following code: 
`usernames = [];` is not a good way of resetting the current array as the variable is redeclared and the **reference to the original array (That autocomplete uses) is lost**. So my console was showing my usernames array with new values but Autocomplete wasn't showing any new values at all.

Thankyou to @Twisty for offering help even though I didn't supply some of the code I was using. His fiddle helped me clear a lot of stuff up.

I ended up clearing the array by using:

```
usernames.length = 0;
```

New code:

```
$('#userInput').autocomplete({
    source: usernames,
    search: "",
    minLength: 0
  }).keyup(function(){
  var inputField = $(this);
  var site = $('#site').val();
  var url = "/AJAX/SearchUsers.do?searchQ="+inputField.val()+"&site="+site;

  if (inputField.val().length > 3){
    $.ajax(url, {
      type: "GET",
      datatype: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        taggedData = data;
        for (var i =0; i < data.length; i++) {
          usernames.push(data[i].username);
      }
    }
  });
}
  $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
  usernames.length = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the jQuery UI API:

> **search( [value ] )**
>
> Triggers a search event and invokes the data source if the event is
>   not canceled. Can be used by a selectbox-like button to open the
>   suggestions when clicked. When invoked with no parameters, the current
>   input's value is used. Can be called with an empty string and
>   minLength: 0 to display all items.

This could be executed like so:

```
$('#userInput').focus(function(){
  $(this).autocomplete( "search", "" );
});
```

To answer your question, yes, there is a way. See more: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search

Example Code: https://jsfiddle.net/4muo4pf0/