# Jquery ui autocomplete - instant list, and multiple select

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Is it possible to have the suggestion list display without typing any characters, and also have the list show multiple times, after an initial selection for multiple selections?
I have tried several different ways, and can get one or the other, but not both..

Code makes list appear on focus...

```
 $(itemInput).autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: phrases,
      multiselect: true
    }).on("focus", function () {
      $(this).autocomplete("search", '');
    }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
      console.log(item);
      let imageFile = item.label.replace(/\s/g, '-').replace(/\//, '').replace(/\./g, '_');
      return $("<li>").append("<div>" +
          "<img class='acImage' src='" + imagePath + imageFile + ".svg'/>" +
          "<div class='acName'>" + item.value + "</div>" +
          "</div>")
          .appendTo(ul);
    };
```

Comment: I think you are looking for a tag input type plugin?

Comment: you can raise an event on document.ready, can you post what you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: Read: [Autocomplete with multiple selected](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple). Hitting the down arrow, without typing first, will show all preloaded values.

Comment: try using [select2](https://select2.org/)

Comment: Honestly not sure, at the moment I have it setup where the list shows on focus of the input, but everything I have seen so far for multiple selections disables that focus... Then pushes the new selections....

Comment: Post the code that you have and we might be able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks Brainfeeder, will do post it later.

Comment: @Brainfeeder just added the code I am using that works for the list to appear on focus.

Comment: @Simon take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625681/jquery-autocomplete-pre-filtered-results-show-all/36629368#36629368